# Using Safari to list all contents of a folder/path

Tags: safari, folders

Is there a way I can use Safari to list the contents of a folder? More like of an "index" page where you get to see the files and sub-folders inside a path/folder. Like this one:[image]

When I use Chrome, I just type the tilde "~" character on the address bar, which many of us know, represents the "home directory" of the OS. It's easy for me because Chrome just lists all the files under that directory in a list format inside the browser. I can just click the HTML files or any file/folder for that matter to view its content.

I know this can be done just by using Finder to navigate your directories and files, but it's much easier to just click around files where you know it will still end up displaying in the browser.

As I have tested, when typing the path or even "~" in the address bar, what it does is either do a web search or open that folder in Finder. Just not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. I looked at a list of Safari Extensions, and no extension I found has this ability.

**NOTE**: If you put the actual URL path description in the Safari address bar, ex: `file:///Users/Panoy`, Safari will open a Finder window to that path, not display the path in the browser window itself.